# Textview textIsSelectable inside Listview does not work

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview, and have an image and text in it. Here is the related xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivBoughtAndWonListItemImage"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:background="@drawable/grid_product_sample" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBoughtAndWonListProductID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ivBoughtAndWonListItemImage"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sampleProductCode"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my list adapter is like the following:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>{


public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when i long click on the textview to select and copy it, adapter's getview() is called, and list is refreshed and i do not see the context bar at top in order to copy the text and also the cursor is not also shown, the list is refreshed. So, how can i copy the text inside listview?

**EDIT:** My app is in **landscape** mode, i noticed that if i change my app to portrait mode, this does not happen and copying works fine. Can that be a bug of android? Has anyone noticed that behavior before?

Thanks.

Comment: please post the code where you have implemented listView.setOnItemLongClickListener().

Comment: @DroidAks i did not implement any long click listener. When "textIsSelectable" is set true for a textview, android normally handles text selection.

Comment: Did you test only on one device? Try testing on different devices (including emulator) and API levels and see if it behaves the same, i.e. to work only in portrait mode.